# Error Code Visual Studio error:c2059 strange syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

as iam using Visual Studio 2013 i got an compile error which i can't solve. Here is the line of code

```
std::vector<std::pair<Vector2D*, Vector2D*>> m_joystickValues;
```

On MSDN they say following to this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf.aspx

Now i dont really know how to change the code to work. As i see no mistake in writing this code above. Can you help me with clear answer?

The Compiler says:

> Fehler    3   error C2059: Syntaxfehler:
>   ','   c:\users\andreas\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\sdlproject\sdlproject\inputhandler.h    42  1   SDLProject

Comment: sry, doesnt work at all

Comment: What is directly above this line of code? And regardless of that, make sn SSCCE, because the answers submitted so far are correct about legacy tools. You can also further isolate this by breaking that line into two typedefs, four if absolutely necessary, before the actual var decl.

Comment: @user3302514: please read [this](http://sscce.org/), WhozCraig already referred to it in his/her comment.

Answer (score 2):

This has been a longstanding issue with templates. Use `> >` (some whitespace between the two closing angle brackets) instead of `>>` so that the compiler doesn't confuse it with shift right.

---

As pointed out correctly in the comments, for the latest toolchain in Visual Studio 2013, this should not be an issue. But since Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 can use other toolchains I didn't want to make that assumption.

Comment: sry but this isn't working. Syntax highlighting is correct but still same compile error.

Comment: If he is using VC 2013 then writing `>>` should be fine, unless his project is set to use older platform toolset (compiler) version.

Comment: Well o MSDN they tell about the template keyword to use, but i dont understand how to use it

Comment: @user3302514: if that's the case, you haven't given us enough information.

Comment: @user3302514 but you haven't given the information we asked for. See the comments on the question. And yes, I saw the link and fixed it to point to the English version of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Yes "> >" instead of ">>" in your declaration